# ExpressibleByFloatLiteralの付属型のデフォルト

Tags: swift, swift3

リテラルと型について勉強中です。

ExpressibleByFloatLiteralの次の付属型は、既定型としてDouble型となっているそうですが、
ソースでは、

associatedtype FloatLiteralType : _ExpressibleByBuiltinFloatLiteral

と記述されているようです。※GitHubに上がっているソースから参照しただけですが。。。

associatedtype FloatLiteralType : _ExpressibleByBuiltinFloatLiteral = Double

と記述されているなら理解できますが、なぜデフォルトが、Double型となるのでしょうか。

またAppleリファレンスで、「FloatLiteralType」で検索したところ、「typealias FloatLiteralType = Double」と記述されていましたが、どこでこれらの宣言がおこなわれているのでしょうか。教えてください。

Comment: 「ExpressibleByFloatLiteralの次の付属型は、既定型としてDouble型となっているそうです」の出典を明らかにしてください。

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6d1ae2a3/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift#L72 ですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

規定というか、

```
struct S : ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
  init(floatLiteral: FloatLiteralType) {}
}
```

と書いた場合に、なぜ `S.FloatLiteralType` が `Double` になるかっていう事ですよね？

上記ソースで `FloatLiteralType` は `S.FloatLiteralType` を参照しているのではなくて、グローバルの `Swift.FloatLiteralType` つまり `typealias FloatLiteralType = Double` を参照している状態です。(Xcodeで command + クリックしてみると分かります。)

で、プロトコルの制約から `associatedtype FloatLiteralType` が類推されて `S.FloatLiteralType` が `Double` になります。

自前で書くとしたらこんな感じです。

```
typealias AssocTy = Int

protocol P {
  associatedtype AssocTy
  func foo(x: AssocTy)
}

class C : P {
  func foo(x: AssocTy) {}
}

C.AssocTy.self == Int.self // true
```